# Approximating continuous functions with growth condition by lipschitz functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I wonder about the following. Is it possible to approximate $x^p$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}_+$ with lipschitz continuous functions? If so, is it possible to approximate it in a dominating way, i.e. $f_n\to x^p, f_n$ lipschitz and $f_n\ge x^p$? The convergence does not have to be uniform, pointwise would be fine.

If we need additional assumption, please let me know. Also any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: what range do you want $p$ in?

Comment: @Tom we assume $p\ge 2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approximation by below ($f_n(x)\leqslant x^p$) can be obtained, taking $f_n(x):=\min\{n,x^p\}$.

But it's not possible for approximations by above: 
$$\frac{f_n(n)-f_n(0)}{n-0}\geqslant \frac{n^p-f_n(0)}{n}\to \infty$$
if $p\gt 1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why exactly are $f_n$ are lipschitz? if, $x^p,y^p<n$, we have $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|=|x^p-y^p|$ and for $p\ge 2$, this must not be less than $K|x-y|$

Comment: The $K$ will depend on $n$.

Comment: depend in what way? linearly or also power of $p$?

Comment: Yes, also on $p$, for example $|x^p-y^p|\leqslant |x-y|n^{p-1}$.

Comment: Is it true generally that $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\le n^{p-1}|x-y|$ and how did you get this inequality?

Comment: We can use the mean values theorem. It's probably not sharp.

Comment: But then we need another $p$, i.e. $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\le p n^{p-1}|x-y|$

Comment: You are right (I should have made the computations more carefully).

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. But how do you deal with the case, $|x^p-n|$, i.e. $f_n(y)\ge n$? How do you get $|x^p-n|\le pn^{p-1}|x-y|$. Of course we just have to look at the case, where $|x-y|<1$.

Comment: We have $|x^p-n|=|f(x)-f(n^{1/p})|\leqslant pn^{p-1}|x-n^{1/p}|$ and $|x-n^{1/p}|$ is in this case smaller  than $|x-y|$.